# Getting unwanted characters in response from service

Tags: java, json, rest

Getting unwanted characters in response.

I have a simple Restful service that takes objects as input and converts them into JSON string and returns it back. I am using google json api for this task. However all the "=" is getting converted to "\u003d" in the response from the service.

Input to the service:

```
[{PageViewEvent=PageViewEvent{pageName=Home Page, pageType=Home}}]
```

Output from service:

```
"[{PageViewEvent\u003dPageViewEvent{pageName\u003dHome Page, pageType\u003dHome}}]"
```

## Service.java

```
@POST
@Path("/events")
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String handlePost(String events) {
    log.debug("before: " + events);
    String jsonResponse = JsonConverter.toJSON(events);
    log.debug("atfter: " + jsonResponse);
    return jsonResponse;
}
```

Please guide.

Comment: `\u003d` _is_ an equal sign

Comment: Shouldn't it be `:` instead of `=`?

Comment: I am not sure. Is it recommended to have JSON strings with ":" instead of "=" ?

Comment: @user2325154 Standard JSON does not appear to recognize the `=` symbol: http://json.org/. I see absolutely no reference to it in the definition grammar. I could imagine that contributing to the problem, although I'm not sure how the parser would even handle that input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got rid of the problem by replacing

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
```

with

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
```